# Reading the rowset of mySQL database returned by row = mysql_fetch_row(result) which is a string array to extract individual fields from it 

Tags: mysql, c, database

When i try to use the code, I find that row[i] is the i'th row in the form of a string. But I need to use my data which was in the form of a int. Also, the row[i] contains the entire row in the form of a string. How do I extract the data from it. I tried to parse the data and convert it into integer, but the entire data is just one string and does have any spaces! so i am having a difficult time doing the parsing as I have no way to know where the previous field ended and the next began in the dataset.

So to sum it up;

when i do:

```
mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "abcd", "Hybr", 0, NULL, 0);
    mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM Data");
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);

    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
            for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
            {
                  row[i]  //this is a string containing all the 
                                  //fields. I want the individual values !

            }
  }
```

My Data 34, 45, host gets converted into a string "34 45 host". And the wierd thing is that when i print row[i], atleast it prints the spaces but when i copy it into a char*, the space somehow disappears! so it becomes impossible to parse it.

I think there is a different way of reading records ,maybe I have overlooked some part of the API, but i cant seem to find which ...

### EDIT

I realised I havent overlooked the API; its just that the row[i] is an array of strings. I still need help extracting the individual values from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use atoi on the field if you know it will be int. For example, units is int and so "SELECT units FROM data" could be read into an int array or whatever.

```
mysql_query  conn, "SELECT units FROM data"
res = mysql_store_result(conn)
num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res)
while  (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
    for  i = 0; i < num_fields; i++
        printf  "%03i ",atoi(row[i])
    puts  ""
```

Comment: I guess I should add before somebody else does that strtol() would be a more robust solution because it can be checked for error conditions to warn you if the database changes.